# Bootstrap 4 div after the row causes issues for columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap grid, if I add another class after the row, then the columns are messed up. So in this example, the content is shown below each other instead of having two equal columns

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="inside">

       <div class="col-sm-6">
           <p>sample content</p>
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>sample content</p>
       </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

here is [a live demo](https://www.bootply.com/GfWRjz0iDM) using bootstrap 4 with problem
and here [is the live demo](https://www.bootply.com/4DhkFOAdVf) with bootstrap 3 which works without any issue.

the same structure works fine on bootstrap 3.x, just not with bootstrap 4.

The issue is with adding `<div class="inside">` after `row` which I should add (I can't remove it). Any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
.inside {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The reason is Bootstrap 4 now uses flex to display grid, so .row basically has a property of display: flex;. You only need to make the inside div replicate the behavior.

Comment: this solution is not responsive, so if you go on mobile view, both columns are 50% where they should be 100% on small screens

Comment: Thanks for pointing that up. Updated my answer to include flex-wrap property.